# Force Django to Consider Join Table in makemigrations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

I needed to change my foreign key on my `User` model from a UUIDField to an IntegerField. I did this in two steps:

1. Rename the current primary key from `id` to `old_id` and run a migration. This generated a `RenameField` operation.
2. Deleted the `old_id` field entirely from User so that the automatic `id` field would take over. This generated a `RemoveField` operation on `old_id` and an `AddField` operation for a `models.AutoField` named `id`. Perfect. The database shows that `User` now has an `int id` field, auto-incrementing.

Then I went to run the app and quickly ran into a problem: the database join tables automatically generated by the `models.ManyToManyField`s on User (e.g. `user_languages` weren't updated - they still have both a `language_id` AND a `user_id` that are UUID data types. There is no foreign key constraint in the database, but there are indexes on that field.

How can I force Django to regenerate those join tables with the new data type for the `User.id` column?

Notes: `manage.py makemigrations` doesn't pick up any pending changes. Also, I'm OK with losing the data in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove/comment out fields from the model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # languages = models.ManyToManyField('Language')
    # other fields
```

Then generate a migration. Then uncomment the line(s). Then run another migration.

**Warning**: This will cause those tables to be dropped and re-created, so all those relationships will be lost.